# IntegrityError at /doctor/Appointment/

Tags: django

my code

here is my model

i am getting null constrain error

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patient_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,
    null=True,blank=True)
    date_of_birth=models.DateField(null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    mobile_number=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    family_members=models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_name

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.mobile_number


class Doctor(models.Model):
    doctor_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    email_id=models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    doctor_number=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.doctor_name


class Appointment(models.Model):
    user_name=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='first')
    mobile_no=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='second')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

here is my viewset

```
class AppointmentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self,request):
        user_name=request.data.get('user_name')
        mobile_no=request.data.get('mobile_no')
        new=Appointment()
        new.user_name=user_name
        new.mobile_no=mobile_no
        new.save()
        return Response({'done':True})
```

Comment: Please post the error traceback so the issue can be seen.

Comment: ValueError at /doctor/Appointment/
Cannot assign "'ashu'": "Appointment.user_name" must be a "Patient" instance.
Request Method: POST

Comment: `user_name` and `mobile_no` are foreign keys, they expect an record assigned, not a string or int.

Comment: so what should i do now

Comment: Why does your title say `IntegrityError` and your comment talk about a `ValueError`. Which one is it? Those are 2 different errors.

Comment: You need to assign a `Patient` instance to `new.user_name` and to `new.mobile_no`, so fetch the patient with the username you got and fetch the patient with the mobileno you got and use those instead.

Comment: then that data will be strored in patience,i want the fields of Patient to give data to Appointment

Comment: solved,anyways thanks for help